# Ubuntu 16.04 Mysql update broke root login

Tags: server, login, mysql

After regular update mysql stop me from login I had root user with no password for local host.

```
|  innodb_version          | 5.7.15                  |

| protocol_version        | 10                      |

| tls_version             | TLSv1,TLSv1.1           |

| version                 | 5.7.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
```

I can log in into server with

```
 mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

but got error

```
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'test';
ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin 'auth_socket' is not loaded
```

How to change actually password for root??

Answer (score 3):

Do a 
`cat /etc/mysql/debian.cnf` on your terminal.

The file contents displayed should contain username and password of 2 users.

Use any of these credentials to access your `mysql`.

Change root password on the `mysql` prompt.

run `flush privileges`;

Now exit the MySQL pront and try logging in as `root`, it should work.

Comment: Make sure to accept the answer that works by clicking the tick.

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution of Ayush didn´t work. When using the credentials defined in `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf` I got the error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Instead it worked with a solution presented [here](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/03/16/change-user-password-in-mysql-5-7-with-plugin-auth_socket/):

I logged in with

> mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &

and on the mysql prompt I entered

> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'test';

Afterwards I could log in to MySQL the normal way.